# Какая лицензия нужна для моего проекта

Tags: лицензирование, opensource

буду краток.

Я имею опенсурс проект,хочу выложить на гитхаб,и у меня возникла проблема с тем что я не знаю какую лицензию мне взять к моему случаю.

Мой случай: Если проект в котором используется мой опенсурс является коммерческим,или закрытым ,то они должны будут выплачивать проценты,если проект будет опенсурс,то ничего,также они смогут модифицировать,изменять,но  при этом обязаны указывать моё авторство.

Comment: За «процентами» лучше сразу к юристам, вряд ли здесь есть соответствующие специалисты

Comment: @andreymal, ок, спасибо.